# ModeShape 3.0 on JBoss Application Server 7.1

Tags: jboss, jcr, federation, modeshape

I am trying to setup ModeShape AS7 Kit on JBoss Application Server 7.1.1. The ModeShape has the following structure.

```
/docs
   /schema
      modeshape_1_0.xsd
/modules
   /javax/jcr/*
   /org/modeshape/*
   /org/hibernate/search-engine/4.1/*
   /org/apache/lucene/3.5/*
/standalone
   /configuration/
      standalone-modeshape.xml
   /deployments
      /modeshape-rest.war/
         .dodeploy
         /META-INF/*
         /WEB-INF/*
```

Could somebody help on where these files to be copied to JBoss AS7 installation directories in order for ModeShape to be up and running?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE/ModeShape+and+JBoss+AS7), which includes instructions for installing the ModeShape kit for AS7. It actually is as simple as unzipping the kit over the top of an existing AS7 installation.

The kit includes a sample configuration, but it's better if you create a configuration that suits your own needs. The best way to do that is [using](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE/Configuring+ModeShape+in+AS7) AS7's command line interface to set up the Infinispan caches, security, and repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Worked:

Copy and paste all the contents from ModeShape AS Kit into JBoss's Application Server's directories(if they exist or they will be copied from ModeShape source) and run the JBoss's

```
./standalone.sh -c="standalone-modeshape.xml".
```

Enjoy :)